# How to get r_basicprofile access for linke in APIs

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Am trying to call 
`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/q=firstName&firstName={name}` but getting the following error

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /people/q=firstName&firstName=ahmed",
    "status": 403
}
```

How to enable my account to get access on `r_basicprofile` access

Answer (score 3):

According to the [migration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context), access to the basic profile fields is being restricted to developers that are members of the partner program. So you'll have to apply to a partner program to access those fields. However, LinkedIn has no clear documentation on which partner program developers should use for the simple use case of maintaining access to r_basicprofile. I've talked with a couple of their customer service reps and they eventually directed me to ask about it here but it seems no one has a clear answer for this...

Comment: Well, do you have more info now? I'm still searching